# devise+omniauth-facebook, where can I find the auth hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I need to change the image size, so where can I find that hash that contains all the info returned? I am using devise
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

auth hash is stored in `env["omniauth.auth"]`, look for it in your callback controller

```
data = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
```

this data contains all your info. Facebook provides 4 sizes for image `small, square, large, normal`.
And you can set the default size for image in `config/initializers/omniauth.r`b as,

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
  provider :facebook, ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :image_size => 'large'
end
```

**Update**:
 If you are using devise, check in your `app/config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
 Devise.setup do |config|
...
  config.omniauth :facebook,  ENV['FACEBOOK_KEY'], ENV['FACEBOOK_SECRET'], :image_size => 'large'
...
end
```

Comment: I don't have an omniauth.rb file because I am using devise.